# Error importing .dmp file in oracle.

Tags: oracle10g

I am trying to import a .dmp file using impdp command. Whenever I try that I get following error logs:

```
Import: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wednesday, 27 July, 2011 19:22:18

Copyright (c) 2003, 2005, Oracle. All rights reserved.
;;;
Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
Master table "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01": system/******** DUMPFILE=HIST_IR_APR_2011.dmp
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
ORA-39083: Object type TABLE failed to create with error:
ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Partitioning
Failing sql is:
CREATE TABLE "DBO"."HIST_IR" ("IR_ID" NUMBER(9,0), "ELS_ID1" NUMBER(9,0), "ELS_ID2" NUMBER(9,0), "ZONE_ID" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, "TYPE" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, "START_TIME" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, "END_TIME" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, "ROAD_NAME" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, "UP_POINT" NUMBER(4,2), "DN_POINT" NUMBER(4,2), "UP_LINK_ID" NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, "DN_LINK_ID" NUMBER
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
ORA-39112: Dependent object type OBJECT_GRANT:"DBO" skipped, base object type TABLE:"DBO"."HIST_IR" creation failed
ORA-39112: Dependent object type OBJECT_GRANT:"DBO" skipped, base object type TABLE:"DBO"."HIST_IR" creation failed
ORA-39112: Dependent object type OBJECT_GRANT:"DBO" skipped, base object type TABLE:"DBO"."HIST_IR" creation failed
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
ORA-39112: Dependent object type INDEX:"DBO"."INDX_HIST_IR_LOC_TYPE" skipped, base object type TABLE:"DBO"."HIST_IR" creation failed
ORA-39112: Dependent object type INDEX:"DBO"."INDX_HIST_IR_ROAD_NAME" skipped, base object type TABLE:"DBO"."HIST_IR" creation failed
ORA-39112: Dependent object type INDEX:"DBO"."INDX_HIST_IR_ELS_ID1" skipped, base object type TABLE:"DBO"."HIST_IR" creation failed
ORA-39112: Dependent object type INDEX:"DBO"."PK_HIST_IR" skipped, base object type TABLE:"DBO"."HIST_IR" creation failed
ORA-39112: Dependent object type INDEX:"DBO"."INDX_HIST_IR_START_TIME" skipped, base object type TABLE:"DBO"."HIST_IR" creation failed
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
ORA-39112: Dependent object type CONSTRAINT:"DBO"."PK_HIST_IR" skipped, base object type TABLE:"DBO"."HIST_IR" creation failed
Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" completed with 10 error(s) at 19:22:21
```

Any idea how to get rid of the errors ?

Also Can I use Oracle Developer 6.0 to process this .dmp file without first having to import this by above procedure ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the source database has the partitioning option enabled and created a partitioned table.  The destination database, on the other hand, does not have the partitioning option.

Are you licensed to use the partitioning option on the destination database?  This is an extra cost option on top of the enterprise edition license.  If you are licensed to use it, you'll want to install that option before doing the import.

If you are not licensed to use the partitioning option, what do you want to happen to the partitioned table?  Do you want to create a non-partitioned table in the destination database and load all the data anyway?  How do you want to handle any local indexes on the partitioned table?

In the latter case, one option would be to run the import initially with the `INDEXFILE` option specified.  That will write the DDL for the table and index creation to a text file.  You could go into this text file, grab the DDL for the partitioned table and indexes, modify the DDL to remove the partitioning options and to add the partition key to any local indexes, and run the new DDL against the target database.  You could then do the import again with the `IGNORE=Y` option to ignore creation errors since you've created the partitioned table manually.  That will import all the data into the non-partitioned table.  You may still have errors in any code that references the table and expects it to be partitioned and you may have performance problems if the queries that hit this table need it to be partitioned.